# cannot convert node** to node** error for this given code in c

Tags: c, data-structures

I am getting "cannot convert node** to node** error" for the given code.
Here both are node**.
Error is getting while the function  insertintoBST is compared to its declaration.
node is a structure variable.
Here, I have tried to implement insertion  into a binary search tree.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void inserttoBST(struct node**,int,int);

void main()
{
    int choice,i,j;

    struct node{
    int value;
    int key;
    struct node*left;
    struct node*right;
    };

    struct node*root=NULL;

    do{
        printf("\n1.insert\n2.delete\n3.view list\n4.search");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: printf("\nEnter the key and data :");
                scanf("%d%d",&i,&j);
                inserttoBST(&root,i,j);
                break;
            case 2: break;
            case 3:break;
            case 4:break;
            default:printf("\nInvalid Entry");
        }
   }while(choice!=10);
}


void inserttoBST(struct node**root,int keys,int val)
    {
    if(*root==NULL)
        {
        struct node*nodes=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        nodes->key=key;
        nodes->val=val;
        nodes->left=nodes->right=NULL;
        *root=nodes;
        }
    else if((*root)->key<keys)
        inserttoBST((*root)->right,int keys,int val);
    else    inserttoBST((*root)->left,int keys,int val);
    }
```

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

Comment: Also, as per c standard, please use `int main(void)`

Comment: Thank you for the support.. The error is because the structure is defined within main function.

Comment: `struct node` definition is not visible outside `main()`. Change the definition to put into global space, or better, in a header file.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: A header file is only better if the definition is intended to be visible beyond this single source file.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth absolutely right. Thanks for the clarification. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *first* problem is that `struct node` is not declared at the first point where you use it.

You need to move the definition out of `main` to before the `inserttoBST` prototype.

That's the first of *many* problems that code has, you also need to look at:

- getting rid of `conio.h`, it's not a standard header.
- including `stdlib` since that's needed for `malloc`.
- figuring out whether your key variable should be `key` or `keys`.
- figuring out whether your value structure field should be `val` or `value`.
- getting rid of the `int` type specifiers from your *calls* to `inserttoBST`.
- passing the correct value as the first argument to `inserttoBST`, specifically something like `&((*root)->leftOrRight)`.
- use `int main (void)` for the main function, this is one of the two canonical variants specifically allowed for by the standard.

That's everything I had to do to get it to *compile,* whether that's enough to remove any logic errors I couldn't say.

But, once you've got it to compile, that'll be the next step you need to take.